# Sort list of objects by attribute, but attribute contains name, numbers and underscores PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

A user has asked this question on here but it was in regards to a list of strings. I have a list of classes and want to modify the answer in this question:

[original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077432/sorting-list-of-file-name-with-text-number-and-underscore-in-python/60077798#60077798)

Specifically, this code, works exactly the way I want but I need to modify it to work with class attributes not just a list of strings:

````
import re
## ref: https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/
def sort_nicely( l ):
    """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect.
    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c.replace("_","")) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    l.sort( key=alphanum_key )
    return print(l)
    ```
````

I've tried modifying the lambda expression in many ways but no matter how I modify it I always get the following error:

> expected string or bytes-like object

Here is where I am currently at, which does not work. Any insights will be much appreciated

```
import re

class ContainerTest:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.name = ''
        
def sort_nicely( l ):
    """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect.
    """
    convert = lambda x: x.name, lambda text: int( x ) if x.isdigit() else x
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert( c.replace( "_", "" ) ) for c in re.split( '([0-9]+)', key ) ]
    l.sort( key=alphanum_key )
    return print( l )

items = []

for i in range( 0, 2 ):
    item = ContainerTest()
    item.name = 'test_128_0' + str( i + 1 )
    items.append( item )
for i in range( 0, 2 ):
    item = ContainerTest()
    item.name = 'test_64_0' + str( i + 1 )
    items.append( item )

sort_nicely( items )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort your `ContainerTest` instances by their names (using the logic developed to sort strings), you just need to make the `key` function you're sorting with get the attribute from the object it's being passed. The important variable is the `key` argument passed to `alphanum_key`, which will be the item in the list (an instance of the class, in this case).

Try:

```
alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert( c.replace("_", ""))
                            for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key.name)]
```

The change is at the end of the line, where we do the regex split on `key.name` rather than `key`.

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU! Ah I was looking about it the wrong way, this is super good to know. Thanks for the help!